# Is there a way to create/define a ArrayCopy with methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods, switch-statement, copy

Question: As of know I have defined original array in method which is read in another method and in main. It seems to create an issue when I try to copy into new array, unable to add +1 to arraycopy. If I skip new array everything work as intended. Can easily create a method for print arraycopy. Or would it  be better to create the array only in main?

**Error:**
I know my problem is here: (Plenty of pictures).
[ArrayCopyError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykO8y.png)

1. if (names.length < 24
   Despite names being less then 24 it still goes to else {System.out.println("Array is full");.
2. I might have complicated the ArrayCopy. 1.1 I defined the **first array Name names in method readFile** and the rest in **main Name[] names = readFile("names.txt")**. Yes all the array elements is in file, so no elements is created outside that the switch case 1 is where other objects will be added.

readFile: (Without the arrayCopy it work as expected).
[Array def 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyY47.png)

Main def 2. (Without the arrayCopy it work as expected).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl0Nx.png)

What I should do:
//   Create a new array of size n+1, where n is the size of the original array.
I know I have to measure names.length and create equal size copy and add 1.
As shown in pictures I have tried to add 1 but it does not really like it.

```
//   Add the n elements of the original array in this array.
Some variant of:
copyArray = names[0];
copyArray = names[1]
continue....
```

Probably not the best way I could add the objects in file to copy, but it is a loop so new ones might be added.

```
//   Add the new element in the n+1 position.
//   Print the new array.
Could be same as method: printNames
```

**Tried:**
I have tried this one, it´s the most closely related to mine but I have **converted it to String**, I had to change the copyArray[i] = intArray[i]; copyArray[0]++; which I believe to be related to the readFile. Also removed the printing of the arrays since I do have the **method printNames(Name[]names)**.Could possibly create the same method but for the arraycopy.
[Try1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGHw0.png)

[Try1 and Try2 is from this website](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/java-copy-array/)

[Try2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX85y.png)

[Potential candidate Stream API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-copy)

```
String[] strArray = {"orange", "red", "green'"};

String[] copiedArray = Arrays.stream(strArray).toArray(String[]::new);
```

**In textfile:**
Spock       Nimoy

Xena        Warrior

Jane        Tarzan

Phil        Collins

Yoongi      RM

Jackson     Wang

---

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package fileObjectTutorial;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


/**
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class FileObjectTutorial {
    
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {
    
        //read file
        Name[] names = readFile("names.txt");
        //print names
        printNames(names);

           String fNamn;
           String eNamn;
           
           int fortsatta = 0;
           int counter = 0;
           int val;
           Scanner scanObj = new Scanner(System.in);

     while(fortsatta == 0){

           System.out.println("Fyll  i:\n1 Add name\n2 " + "closed\n3 " + "closed\n4 " + "closed");
           val = scanObj.nextInt();
           
        switch(val){
        
           case 1:
               System.out.println("1");
               for(int i =0; i<names.length; i++) {
                   if (names.length <= 24) {
                       String copyNames [] = new String[names.length];
                       System.out.println("Type in firstname and lastname: ");
                       Scanner copy = new Scanner(System.in);
                       fNamn = copy.next();
                       eNamn = copy.next();
                       Name k_obj = new Name(fNamn, eNamn);
                           names[counter] = k_obj;
                           counter++;
                           if(names != null || copyNames != null) {
                        //     System.out.print(names[i] + " ");
                        //     System.out.print(copyNames[i] + " ");
                           copy.close();
                           }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       counter = names.length-1;
                       System.out.println("Array is full");
                       }
                   
               }
                 
                 break;
        case 2:
               System.out.println(".");
               
           case 3:
               System.out.println(".");
               break;
           case 4:
                   System.out.println(".");
                   break;
            default:
                   System.out.println(".");
                   } //slut switchsats
                   System.out.println("Go 0 Stop 1");
                   fortsatta = scanObj.nextInt();
                 }

                   scanObj.close();
                   System.out.println("end");
                   }    

               
public static void printNames(Name[]names){
    //iterate throught array
    for(Name n : names){
        //print each name
        if (n != null)
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }   

public static Name[] readFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Name[] list = new Name[25];
    int count = 0;
    //open file
    File fileNames = new File(filename);
    if(fileNames.canRead()){
        //get scanner on file
        Scanner namedata = new Scanner(fileNames);

        //sentinel loop on hasNext
        while (namedata.hasNext()){
            //read firstname
            String namefirst = namedata.next();
            //read lastname
            String namelast = namedata.next();
            //build the name and put in array
            list[count] = new Name(namefirst, namelast);
            count++; 
            }
        namedata.close();
        }
    //return array
    return list;
    }

}


class Name {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;

        //constructor
        /**
        * null constructor - empty name
        */
        public Name(){
            this.setFirstName("");
            this.setLastName("");
            }
        /**
        * full constructor based on first and last name
        */
        public Name(String firstName, String lastName){
            this.setFirstName(firstName);
            this.setLastName(lastName);
            }
                
        
        //getters & setters
        /**
        * get the first name
        */
        public String getFirstName(){
            return this.firstName;
            }

        /**
        * get the last name
        */
        public String getLastName(){
            return this.lastName;
            }

        /**
        * set the first name
        *
        * @param firstName
        */
        public void setFirstName(String firstName){
            this.firstName = firstName;
            }
        /**
        * set the last name
        *
        * @param lastName
        */
        public void setLastName(String lastName){
            this.lastName = lastName;
            }


        //toString
        //toString
        public String toString(){
            return "Name [firstName = " + this.getFirstName() + ", lastname = " + 
        this.getLastName() + "]";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your original array is always of length 25 as your line shows:
`Name[] list = new Name[25];`

It doesn't matter whether the array is filled with objects or not. Indices without a `Name` object will contain `null`. This means `if (names.length <= 24) {` will always be `false`.

What you can do is change the condition into `if (names[i] == null) {`. You probably don't need the `counter` variable either: `names[counter] = k_obj;` will do the same as `names[i] = k_obj;`

**Regarding the copying of arrays:**

The logic in your `for loop` is flawed. You're creating a new copy array on every iteration. Suppose you have a filled original array and you want to copy it:

```
Name[] original = readFile("someFile.txt");
Name[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(names, names.length);
```